# How to use multiple parameters when sending data as application/json in controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, model-binding

I have the following question:

Currently, I do have an ASP.Net Core Application set up with some generic code in the frontend, which sends all POST requests with a JSON payload and with `application/json` set as content type.

My controllers accept these calls like this for example:

```
public async Task<JsonResponse> AddToPortfolio([FromBody] AddPortfolioUiModel addPortfolioUiModel)
{
     ...
}
```

So, when my frontend code sends a POST for this controller action, it will properly read the parameter UiModel from the JSON.

Good enough.

However, sometimes I do have controller calls which might only require receiving a single `string`. As of now, I would have to wrap this in a model and tag it as `[FromBody]`. This is fairly annoying to do, and I was wondering if there is no easier way to just accept it like this instead:

```
public async Task<JsonResponse> ControllerMethod(string myParam)
{
     ...
}
```

Is this easily possible while still keeping the `application/json` content type attached to all requests coming from my JS client? I don't really want to juggle around with multiple content types, so this would be great.

Comment: If it's just one parameter is sending it through a query parameter an option?

Comment: @milosponj Possible, yes, but for consistency I'd like to keep it as application/json for every call in JS